# Como utilizar o Node.js para executar uma página PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, node.js

O meu caso, está ocorrendo o seguinte: o microcontrolador envia dados usando GET para o servidor, ele salva no banco de dados MySQL e testa se é precisa disparar o alerta. Esse alerta é feito com uma página PHP  que utiliza jQuery+Ajax para enviar para outro servidor, isso já funciona, porém, precisa de um navegador para executar a aplicação jQuery pois é do lado do cliente e não é possível com o microcontrolador. Pesquisei e vi que seria o caso de utilizar Node.js para processar isso no lado do servidor. Aí vem a questão: como eu faria para o Node.js executar essa página PHP?

Comment: Porque estás a misturar Node e PHP? têm de ser ou achas que a solução passa por aí?

Comment: Na verdade é porquê essa página já está funcionando, está pronta e o prazo está curto. Como eu não tenho experiência com Node.js, talvéz fosse menos pior por hora fazer ele "de navegador" para que funcione as funções jQuery na página PHP.

Comment: Ainda estou perdido..., tens um servidor a funcionar com NodeJS ou com PHP? não percebo o que queres dizer com `navegador` e `microcontrolador` (talvez sejam termos que não estou habituado em Portugal). Se tens a página a correr em NodeJS põe aqui o código que tens e di o que te falta fazer. Explica melhor a funcionalidade para percebermos o problema todo.

Comment: Quando digo navegador, me refiro a um browser. O microcontrolador que eu estou utilizando é o Arduino com um Ethernet shield W5100. O caminho é o seguinte: **Arduino** -> **Servidor PHP** -> **MySQL**. Mas no servidor PHP ele vai fazer alguns testes nos dados recebidos, se entrar na condição, ou seja, precisar disparar o comando de emergência seria o seguinte: **Servidor PHP (utilizando jQuery+Ajax)** -> **Outro servidor**. O Arduino como Cliente não roda essa página com jQuery, funcionaria se fosse executado no lado do servidor com o NodeJS, mas teria como ele executar essa página PHP?

Comment: creio que o NodeJS não seja a ferramenta certa para o que você quer. Se explicar melhor a sua estrutura (o que roda em cada lugar e o que quer de resultado) talvez seja possível alguém ajudar.

Comment: Parece que o que você precisa é de um *headless browser*, como o http://phantomjs.org/. Mas não sei se dá para rodar isso num Arduino, eu chutaria que não dá.

Comment: Bruno o que queres dizer com "Servidor PHP (utilizando jQuery+Ajax)"? Sabes que jQuery é uma biblioteca para o lado do cliente certo? Se puderes junta código que queres correr, ou essa página PHP que queres correr para a pergunta ficar mais concreta.

Comment: **Vote hoje! Vote amanhã! Vote sempre! vote consciente!** O seu voto é muito importante para nossa comunidade, contribua conosco e ajude a tornar a Stack Overflow em Português(SOpt) cada vez maior. Você pode saber mais em: [**Vote cedo, vote frequentemente**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/159/vote-cedo-vote-frequentemente)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para o node executar a pagina não vejo problema, você simplesmente configura ele, roda o script que faça a chamada do php e fim, mas acho que a solução mais elegante é fazer o próprio php ficar chamando ele mesmo ( tudo no lado do server )

tenho um caso assim aqui, eu pego informações via SOA como php que grava no meu mysql, antes eu tinha que ficar com um navegar aberto e a pagina que fazia a coleta de dados ali, o script tinha uma recursividade p/ chamar a pagina novamente a cada 30 seg.

pois bem agora eu fiz no shell-script um "processo" que faz esse serviço p/ mim

```
#php arquivo.php &
```

> esse & é importante pois vai garantir que o processo fique rodando
>   mesmo se fechar uma sessão

caso queira saber mais sobre o nodeJS https://nodejs.org/ tem os passos de como configura-lo, é javascript, dali p/ frente é só chamar sua pagina php de forma recursiva da o mesmo resultado porém, é uma instalação/configuração a mais no meu ponto de vista.

( uso nodeJS em outros casos como socket, avisar navegadores do sistema que um evento foi executado e os navegadores passam a executar uma determina instrução javascript, chat é outro exemplo etc. )

Comment: Muito obrigado, Maison. O problema era onde o processamento era feito, não poderia ser do lado do cliente mas já tinha a página pronta, então pensei em usar o Node.js, mas eu resolvi mesmo utilizando o cURL no próprio PHP. Não é tão rápido, isso é notável, mas funciona. Eu consigo fazer a listagem, todos os testes, validações, salvar no banco de dados e enviar as informações, tudo sendo processado do lado do servidor.

Comment: @BrunoMacedo poderia me agradecer com seu votinho também né =D só não se sinta obrigado...rsrsr